# How do i make the entire background of the link change when scrolled over rather than just the text?

Tags: html, css, colors, menu, dropdown

I'm trying to make it so the entire length of the link changes background color however only the background behind the text does.

The html is below:

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdwn.css">
</head>

</body>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <h1><a href="#">Dropdown Box</a></h1>

            <ul class="content">
                <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is below, I have tried changing the padding on many classes but cant seem to get it.

```
body {
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;

}

.dropdown h1 {
    background-color: #62dbfc;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    padding: 15px 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 36px;

}
.content {
    display: none;

}

.dropdown ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.dropdown li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ededed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: calibri;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0px;

}

.dropdown a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 36px;

}

.dropdown:hover .content {
    display: block;
}

.content a:hover {
    background-color: #c4c4c4; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change what you are attaching your `:hover` to and it should highlight the entire `li` element.

```
.content li:hover {
    background-color: #c4c4c4; 

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to change "li" background color instead of "a".
You can use JQuery

```js
$(".li_class").mouseover(function(){
  var color  = $(this).css("background-color");
  $(this).css("background", "#your color");
  $(this).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).css("background", color);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use JQuery when all of this can be accomplished in one css rule.